# How to duplicate all nodes within a node frame?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I often have to duplicate a node frame with all nodes within it. However when I just select the node frame and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it only duplicates the node frame but not the nodes contained within it.
Of course I could manually select all the nodes, but especially with large node setups this quickly becomes quite tedious.

Is there an operation or hotkey that does what I want?

Comment: hi can u kindly mark this thread as resolved?

Comment: Doesn't accepting an answer resolve it automatically? @HarryMcKenzie

Comment: yeah the green check mark does. thanks for closing :)

Comment: By the way the ] shortcut doesn't work for me. I use a non-english keyboard, could it be related to that? @HarryMcKenzie

Comment: when u open notepad and type `]` does it really type that character? if yes then maybe try changing the shortcut in the preferences to something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the *Layout Frame* containing the nodes you want to copy and go to menu *Select -> Select frame's members (children)* or press the shortcut key <kbd>]</kbd> (close square bracket) to select the nodes in it or you can double press <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to select everything including child *Layout Frames* and their children nodes. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to copy selection.

[image]

Comment: ...you never stop learning ;-)

Comment: yeah i just discovered it when i was about to give up, after searching for a python solution XD

Comment: Select frame's member only seems to select it's immediate children. Is there something like "Select **all** frame's member"?

Comment: i assume you have frames within frames? select the frame and double tap key `]` to select everything including child frames with their nodes